# Unable to subscribe channel in Parse from Android device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am developing an Android application and using Parse for push notification. Currently I have a problem when registering new device. I've used the code below to subscribe my Android phone on a specific channel on Parse server.

```
final String channel = "myapp_" + userId;
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(channel, new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(channel, new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("Subscribe", e == null ? "Success" : "Failure");
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.e("Subscribe", "Success");
        }
    }
});
```

I have a strange problem on this:
The device can be registered to Parse for the 1st time after installing apps to phone (my device has already subscribed a channel successfully) but the GCM does not return the device token. Even after I wait for a long time, but nothing good happen. Unless I quit and re-open the apps, then GCM returns device token. I don't know where is the difference between them: the 1st time using apps vs reopen apps.
Have anyone got this problem? And can you give me any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Why are You not saving device Token in very First Time...

Comment: @koutuk: I've used to work with Parse many times before, and they always get the deviceToken from GCM after a few minutes since I register the device. But this time is not, though everything is the same.
I know that we can create a token programmatically at client side, but it will be inconsistent with our general solution in the whole apps, and more risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: the Parse registration must be proceed at `onCreate` action of base `Application` class. Then the `deviceToken` will be retrieved normally on Parse server.